# How could/should I write this SQL query?

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I need to write an SQL query to list a customers prices for our products. We have a standard price list, `customer_no = 0`, and a customer specific price list, `customer_no = XXXX`.

I am having trouble understanding how I can get the query to return the customer specific price for a product, if they've been given such, or if not fall back to the standard price.

**To get all products and prices on the standard price list**

```
select     prices.product_id, products.product_desc, prices.m2
from       prices, products
where      prices.product_id = products.product_id
and        prices.customer_no = 0
order by   prices.product_id asc
```

**To get all products and prices that the customer has been specifically quoted for**

```
select     prices.product_id, products.product_desc, prices.m2
from       prices, products
where      prices.product_id = products.product_id
and        prices.customer_no = $_SESSION['customer']
order by   prices.product_id asc
```

How can I perform the first query, but if the customer has their own price then replace it with that? Is this even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Steve

**Edit:** Sorry, missed the third line in both queries in the original post.

Comment: So it's either the customer price list or the standard price list? Or can there be some prices customer-specific and the others must be taken from the standard list?

Comment: BTW: Hopefully is it just in your example that you cross join the tables. And: What's your Oracle Version? Can't you use explicit joins (INNER JOIN, CROSS JOIN, LEFT JOIN etc.) and must stick to error-prone comma-separated table lists (which have been deprecated in standard SQL for some twenty years now)?

Answer (score 2):

You have to join with the `prices` table twice, once for the list prices and then for the quoted prices. Use a `LEFT JOIN` for the latter, since some products won't have a quoted price. Then use `NVL` to default from the quoted price to the list price.

```
SELECT products.product_id, products.product_desc, NVL(p2.m2, p1.m2)
FROM products
JOIN prices p1 ON p1.product_id = products.product_id
LEFT JOIN prices p2 ON p2.product_id = products.product_id 
                    AND p2.customer_no = $_SESSION['customer']
WHERE p1.customer_no = 0
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I missed a `WHERE` clause (third line) in the question somehow. Where should I add this?

Comment: You mean `prices.product_id = products.product_id`? I already added that in my answer, because I noticed it was missing. It's in the `ON` clauses.

Comment: Thanks. I keep getting `ERROR at line 3: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` but I can't see what's wrong ...

Comment: @user3636943 Table name _doesn't_ need `AS` keyword for alias.(Only Oracle) Just remove it!

Comment: Still get the same error message without the `AS`: `ERROR at line 3:
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.

Comment: Apparently `JOIN` is not valid for Oracle?

Comment: @user3636943 the Query is perfect now, you might be missing something else.

Comment: Clearly it's not, as I get that error message. I'm using Oracle 8, are any functions here not possible in 8? I get the `SQL command not properly ended`. It is regarding the `JOIN` line.

Comment: Oops Oracle 8i??! `JOIN` syntax is modern one. try using `(+)` notation instead of the `JOIN` thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
select     prices.product_id, products.product_desc, prices.m2
from       prices, products
where      prices.customer_no = nvl($_SESSION['customer'], 0)
order by   prices.product_id asc
```

Comment: This doesn't default to the standard price for products that the customer doesn't have a quote for.

Comment: Based on the OP's SQL, the `customer_no` falls back to 0 if there is no customer specified.

Comment: The customer is always specified. But they might not have a special price for some products, then they get the regular price, which comes from customer 0.